# change image dimentions (a, z, y, x) to (x, y, z)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array which is representing an image with shape (1, 3, 480, 640). How would I turn this to have a shape (640, 480, 3)?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to reshape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.squeeze`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) and [`numpy.swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html).

```
img = np.random.rand(1,3,480,640)
img = np.squeeze(img)
print(img.shape)
# (3, 480, 640)

img = np.swapaxes(img, axis1=2, axis2=0)
print(img.shape)
# (3, 480, 640)
```